# Using Facebook and Google Plus login in SoundCloud Android app

Tags: java, android, soundcloud

I have a SoundCloud android app developed with the SoundCloud Java wrapper.

How can I login with Facebook and Google Plus? I couldn't find any clear example. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Do you mean OR? Or are you saying you want the user to have to be signed in to both their fb and g+ simultaneously?

Comment: @Michael, I mean OR. I just want the same thing that the original soundcloud app does.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have familiarity with the SoundCloud java wrapper, however I can pass along information about logging in with Facebook and Google plus with Android applications to hopefully help you.

For Facebook integration, you need to download the Facebook APK. The Facebook developers page details the steps to implement such a login process in Step 6 of their [Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for Android site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/)

For Google Plus integration, you should first enable the Google+ API. They also have a step by step outlined on their development page [Google+ Sign-in for Android](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in).

I also did a quick Google query and found this helpful looking GitHub project aptly called [java-api-wrapper](https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper) that includes a [Facebook connect class](https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper/blob/master/src/examples/java/com/soundcloud/api/examples/FacebookConnect.java).